# Textbox strange behavior when entering space

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, silverlight-5.0, inotifydataerrorinfo

I am using Silverlight 5 and C#. My model (`CustomerModel`) implements `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface to validate user input. The `TextBox` whose Text property is bound to a Property in the model, which is being validated on every keystroke (I have set `UpdateSourceTrigge=PropertyChanged`), is behaving strangely - When I enter space the cursor moves to the beginning of the `TextBox`. Very annoying.

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="txtDebtorName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
           Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
           IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadonly}" >
</TextBox>
```

Any Idea what is causing this behavior, and how to fix it?

The property in the model:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set
    {
        const string propertyName = "Name";
        ValidateRequiredString(propertyName, value, Utility.GetTranslation("RequiredFieldDebtorName"));

        _Name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

The `ValidateRequiredString()` method takes the `PropertyName`, the value being set and an error Message.

Comment: Please elaborate: Does it glitch up every time you press Space? Also, the property looks a bit suspicious, you have a Getter that appears to use a private variable (_Name) while the Setter is setting what looks to be a model's property.

Comment: Yes, if I do not enter any space it works as intended. But as soon as I press space on my keyboard, the cursor moves to the beginning of the text I've typed so far. Don't worry about the property. It's just a normal property with backend field. I've copy paste it and removed some code (to make it look simple). But I forgot to remove some code from the setter part - sorry.